# Grid Gain atomic get-modify-put

Tags: gridgain

What's the best way to atomically modify an object in GG?

```
    GridCache<String, Message> cache = GridGain.grid().cache("message");
    Message message = cache.get(messageId);
    if(message != null) {
        message.setReadDate(new Date());
        cache.putxAsync(messageId, message);
    }
```

I'm hoping to replace it with atomic operation that is executed on the data node

```
    cache.execute(messageId, new Task() {
        public void execute(V value) {
            value.setReadDate();
            return value;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

GridGain has `cache.transform(...)` and `cache.transformAndCompute(...)` methods which work exactly like you need.

Please take a look at [Delta (a.k.a. Partial) Updates](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Delta+%28a.k.a.+Partial%29+Updates) section in documentation.